# Connect database oracle for automation test (robotframework)

Tags: oracle, robotframework, cx-oracle

Can someone help me connecting database oracle on robotframework for data manipulation?

So far I did:

*** Keywords ***

Connect to database

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params  cx_Oracle
    ...  user='${DBUSER}', password='${DBPASS}', dsn='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=${DBHOST})(PORT=${DBPORT})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=${DBName})))'
```

*** Test Cases ***

Connect to database

```
@{queryResults}  Query  SELECT * from tb_example_table
```

log to console  @{queryResults}

But I got error:

```
DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "failed to get message for Windows Error 126". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
```

I tried to install Oracle Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (x64) 64-bit, but I couldn't find any executable file.

Comment: The Instant Client doesn't have an executable or an installer (well, the full client install does have an instant client install as an option).  The intention of the Instant Client is that you'd bundle it with another application you're installing and do the work of doing things like registering the appropriate DLLs.  See the installation instructions at the end of the downloads page, for example https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html .  If you want an executable installer that gives you a GUI, you'd want to download the full client.

Comment: The cx_Oracle installation instructions contain what you need to download and how to install it.   The link is in the error message you quoted.

Comment: yeah, ikr, anyway it doesnt helped me too... But I found a way to solve it, tks!!!